# Create dictionary with string to array of strings (Swift)

Tags: swift, dictionary

If I create a dictionary like the one below

```
var dict: [String: [String]] = [:]
dict["Key 1"] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
```

How can I append an item to the "Key 1" key without rewriting the list.

Something like

```
dict["Key 1"].append("Item 4")
```

But I'm not sure if this works.

Comment: Have you tried it in the xcode playground?

Answer (score 1):

You have to do it like this:

```
    var dict: [String: [String]] = [:]
    dict["Key 1"] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
    dict["Key 1"]?.append("Item 4")
```

Because dict["Key 1"] returns an optional value, which means - it is unclear *during compile time* if the dict will really contain a value with the key "Key 1".

Comment: If you consider this post as answer then please mark it also as answer.

Answer (score 0):

Next Time please create a Playground for that. But this will work for you:

```
dict["Key 1"] = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"]
var temp = dict["Key 1"]
temp?.append("next")
dict["Key 1"] = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

Below you see how to do it....

```
var dict: [String:[String]] = [String:[String]]()
dict["keyOne"] = ["item", "item", "item"]
dict["keyOne"]?.append("new")
println(dict)
```

At first init your dict like you have declared it... than you add an array as value for key "keyOne"... and than append the new value to the array, not to the optional... cheers